# Ignoring blanks in averageifs when data has negative numbers and zero

Tags: google-sheets

I have a formula that will take the data from the past 30 days (column A are dates, column F has the data which is always either blank or above 0).

```
 =AVERAGEIFS(F3:F, A3:A,">"&TODAY()-30, F3:F, ">0")
```

I need another, similar formula to apply to column H, however H will have negative numbers and 0. I would have thought this would work but it is simply not ignoring the blanks and the average does not match when I do a regular average and manually select the non blanks.

```
 =AVERAGEIFS(H3:H, A3:A,">"&TODAY()-30, H3:H, "<>''")
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, it's just:

```
=AVERAGEIFS(H3:H, A3:A,">"&TODAY()-30, H3:H, "<>")
```

That unfortunately wasn't very clear in the documentation.